# Passing variable to Dialogflow Chatbot implemented on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3.x, dialogflow-es, raspberry-pi4

I want to pass some variable into the chatbot (eg. destination = living room, name = John) which is retrieve by the python from local host database. Is there a way to set a simple If/Else rules in the dialog flow chatbot.

Eg....

```
if (destination = "living room") {
    if (location = "bathroom") { 
         response = "Please turn left";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the way you've described it. The easiest way to implement logic is through the [Dialogflow fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview). You can do some basic logic with [Contexts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview), but this gets overly complicated very quickly.